# C compilation error, external library functions not found

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linkage

I'm trying to compile a project (which is written on a 32bit OS, Ubuntu). I'm using the given `makefiles` and I installed all the necessary external libraries (on a 64bit Ubuntu).

I don't get a library linking error but the functions implemented in `SDL` and `argtable2` (external libraries) are not recognized. I only changed the path to the `libSDL_gfx.so` so that it points to the 64bit installation.

How can i solve this compilation issue?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <argtable2.h>

#include "../../problems/generative_model.h"
#include "../../problems/viewer.h"
#include "opcas.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    double discountFactor;
    unsigned int maxNbEvaluations;
    char isTerminal = 0;
    char isDisplayed = 1;
    char verbose = 0;
    unsigned int nbTimestep = 0;
    double L;

    opcas_instance* instance = NULL;

    state* crtState = NULL;
    state* nextState = NULL;
    double reward = 0.0;
    double* optimalAction = NULL;

    struct arg_dbl* g = arg_dbl1("g", "discountFactor", "<d>", "The discount factor for the problem");
...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The makefile looks like:

```
CC := gcc
FLAGS := -W -Wall -g -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic
LIBS := -lm -lSDL -lSDLmain /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_gfx.so -largtable2
BIN_DIR := bin
OBJ_DIR := obj

all: $(BIN_DIR)/opcas_ball $(BIN_DIR)/opcas_inverted_pendulum 
$(BIN_DIR)/opcas_mountain_car $(BIN_DIR)/opcas_acrobot $(BIN_DIR)/opcas_spring_pendulum

$(BIN_DIR)/opcas_ball: $(OBJ_DIR)/opcas_1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/main_opcas_1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/ball.o $(OBJ_DIR)/viewer_ball.o $(OBJ_DIR)/opcas_drawing_procedure_ball.o $(OBJ_DIR)/svgFile.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@
```

The error is (similar error for SDL functions):

```
gcc -W -Wall -g -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic -lm -lSDL -lSDLmain /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-

gnu/libSDL_gfx.so -largtable2 obj/opcas_1.o obj/main_opcas_1.o obj/ball.o 

obj/viewer_ball.o obj/opcas_drawing_procedure_ball.o obj/svgFile.o -o bin/opcas_ball
obj/main_opcas_1.o: In function `main':
/home/elod/UTwork/RealTime_Cpp/continuous_action_space/algorithms/opcas/main_opcas.c:63: undefined reference to `arg_dbl1'
```

Comment: You do not link against .so files, but against .a files.  However you should probably not be explicitly specifying the file to begin with.

Comment: So as the linker seems to miss `arg_dbl1`: Do you know where it is defined, in which module it resides?

Comment: arg_dbl1 is in: `usr/include/argtable2.h` and in the program it is  included `#include <argtable2.h>`

Comment: Please show the declaration/definition(?).

Comment: Do you mean the code segment of the `main.c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options specifying libraries need to go into the command-line **after** the object using symbols out of the libraries given.

So this command:

```
 gcc -W -Wall -g -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic -lm -lSDL -lSDLmain /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_gfx.so -largtable2 obj/opcas_1.o obj/main_opcas_1.o obj/ball.o obj/viewer_ball.o obj/opcas_drawing_procedure_ball.o obj/svgFile.o -o bin/opcas_ball
```

should look like this

```
 gcc -W -Wall -g -ansi -std=c99 -pedantic /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_gfx.so  obj/opcas_1.o obj/main_opcas_1.o obj/ball.o obj/viewer_ball.o obj/opcas_drawing_procedure_ball.o obj/svgFile.o -o bin/opcas_ball -lm -lSDL -lSDLmain -largtable2
```

As a rule of thumb, which would work in nearly all cases: Place `-lxyz` options at the end of the link command.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, in the `makefile` i had to put at the end `$(LIBS)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the source files, compile it in 64 platform and make .so and then link.
Else compile with -m32. It will work

Comment: I installed the SDL and argtable2 libraries with apt-get. This libs should have their `lib*.so`files. For argtable2 I found at  `/usr/lib/libargtable2.so.0.1.7`

Comment: so what do u want to ask.. plz elaborate

Comment: I get the error above while compiling the project. The functions implemented in `argtable2` and `SDL` external libraries are **not recognized**. In the 'main.c' file is included `argtable2.h`. There is no `using namespace ***;` declared in the `main.c`.